# How to send email using Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to send an email but I can't move anymore and that's my view:

```
<h1>Contact TODOParrot</h1>
<form action="contact" method="post">

<div class="form-group">
 <label>Your First Name</label>
 <input type="text" name="Fname" placeholder="Your First Name" />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Your Last Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="Lname" placeholder="Your Last Name" />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label>Your Email</label>
  <input type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Your Email" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Your Phone Number</label>
  <input type="text" name="Phone" placeholder="Your Phone" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Your Order</label>
  <input type="text" name="Order" placeholder="Your Order" />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-default" name="Submit" type="Submit">Send Order</button>
</div>
</form>
```

and that is my controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;  
use App\Http\Requests\ContactFormRequest;
    
class aboutController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function create()
    {
        return view('about.contact');
    }

    public function store(ContactFormRequest $request)
    {
        \Mail::send('about.contact',
        array(
            'Fname' => $request->get('Fname'),
            'Lname' => $request->get('Lname'),
            'Email' => $request->get('Email'),
            'Phone' => $request->get('Phone'),
            'Order' => $request->get('Order')
        ), function($message)
    {
        $message->from('mohamedsasa201042@yahoo.com');
        $message->to('elbiheiry2@gmail.com', 'elbiheiry')->subject('TODOParrot Feedback');
    });

        return \Redirect::route('contact')
      ->with('message', 'Thanks for contacting us!');
    }
}
```

And that's my route:

```
Route::get('contact', 
  ['as' => 'contact', 'uses' => 'AboutController@create']);
Route::post('contact', 
  ['as' => 'contact', 'uses' => 'AboutController@store']);
```

And that's the configuration in the .env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

And I removed the name and password in the question when I press send it gives me 'Forbidden' as a message.

Can anyone help?

Comment: have you configured your email service in Laravel?

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ yes i configured it and i will edit the question to add it

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ i'm using smtp

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ no it only type the word forbidden and nothing is sent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After chatting while with OP, here is the answer.

The main problem:

Your `ContactFormRequest.php` has the following rules function:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
        'name'    => 'required',
        'email'   => 'required|email',
        'message' => 'required',
        ];
    }
```

But your form does not have name and messages, so you need to delete not existing elements or modify them if required, for my testing purpose I did only kept email:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'Email' => 'required|email',
        ];
    }
```

And it is a good practice to keep name conventions like if you use Email with capital `E` than use Email every where.

Therefore the form was never submitted to be send.

I suggest also you structure your `store` function which I have did and test and it works, you can modified it to fit your requirement:

```
$data = [
            'no-reply' => 'contact-from-web@nomail.com',
            'admin'    => 'mohamedsasa201042@yahoo.com',
            'Fname'    => $request->get('Fname'),
            'Lname'    => $request->get('Lname'),
            'Email'    => $request->get('Email'),
            'Phone'    => $request->get('Phone'),
            'Order'    => $request->get('Order'),
        ];

        \Mail::send('about.contact', ['data' => $data],
            function ($message) use ($data)
            {
                $message
                    ->from($data['no-reply'])
                    ->to($data['admin'])->subject('Some body wrote to you online')
                    ->to($data['Email'])->subject('Your submitted information')
                    ->to('elbiheiry2@gmail.com', 'elbiheiry')->subject('Feedback');
            });
```

and it should works,

I have test it only with Mandrill API email service, but you can give it a try with SMTP or API, it is up to you.

If you want to make an email confirmation, you need to create email confirmation view forward your data to it like following:

```
\Mail::send('about.emailconfirmation', ['data' => $data],
```

and your view could looks like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <h1>Contact form</h1>
        <p>Dear {{ $data['Fname'] }},</p>
        <p>Thank you for contacting me.</p>
        <p>I will respond to your inquiry as quickly as possible.</p>
        <hr/>
        <p><b>Provided email</b></p>
        <p>Email: {{ $data['Email'] }},</p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This is only example but you can further modify it.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel app

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465          
MAIL_USERNAME=<<your email address>>
MAIL_PASSWORD=<<app password>>

MAIL_ENCRYPTION= ssl
```

In your Controller Setting

faced

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
```

to Send mail

```
$to_name = "RECEIVER_NAME";
$to_email = "tomail@gmail.com";
$data = array("name"=>"Cloudways (sender_name)", "body" => "A test mail");

Mail::send([], $data, function($message) use ($to_name, $to_email) {
$message->to($to_email, $to_name)
->subject("Laravel Test Mail");
$message->from("preealweb@gmail.com","Test Mail");
});
```

Note: **from mail and to mail**

make sure
enable **SucureLess mail** in gmail setting

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, I think you are missing `authorize` part in your `ContactFormRequest` Goto your this `App/Http/Request/ContactFormRequest` and you will this method

```
public function authorize()
{
    return false;
}
```

so just set return as true. It will allow further process.

```
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}
```

**Edited**

change your `Contact POST Route` to this

```
Route::post('contact/store',['as' => 'contact-store', 'uses' => 'AboutController@store']);
```

and in your form action, just change this.

```
<form action="contact/store" ........
```

Comment: in your store method, 1st check that are you coming properly or not, means on top just made `dd(\Request::all());`

Comment: it repeats the same page with no change

Comment: I just updated my answer, Have a look, I hope that solve your issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105503/discussion-between-qazi-and-mohamed-elbiheiry).

Answer (score 0):

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

i had some similar problem and changed the MAIL_DRIVER = sendmail from smtp

Answer (score 0):

```
Here are three methods to send email in laravel 8.
First one is through our email id.
Second one is through Mailgun.
Third one is through SendinBlue.


# For smtp

# MAIL_MAILER=smtp
# MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
# MAIL_PORT=587
# MAIL_USERNAME=xxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com
# MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
# MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
# MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=xxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com
# MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

# For Mailgun

# MAIL_MAILER=mailgun
# MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
# MAIL_PORT=587
# MAIL_USERNAME=sandboxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mailgun.org
# MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
# MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
# MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
# MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
# MAILGUN_SECRET=API private key
# MAILGUN_DOMAIN=sandboxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mailgun.org

# For sendinblue
# MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
# MAIL_HOST=smtp-relay.sendinblue.com
# MAIL_PORT=587
# MAIL_USERNAME=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com
# MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
# MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
# MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com
# MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```